# Oracle SQL - How to return the name with the highest ID ending in a certain number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structured like this where I need to get the ID's last number, how many people's ID ends with that number, and the person with the highest ID:

```
Members: |ID  |Name      |
         -----------------
         |123 |foo       |
         |456 |bar       |
         |789 |boo       |
         |1226|far       |
```

The result I need to get looks something like this

```
|LAST_NUMBER  |OCCURENCES  |HIGHEST_ID_GUY  |
---------------------------------------------
|3            |1           |foo             |
|6            |2           |far             |
|9            |1           |boo             |
```

However, while I can get the first two results to display correctly, I have no idea how to display HIGHEST_ID_GUY. My code looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(id, LENGTH(id - 1), LENGTH(id)) AS LAST_NUMBER,
COUNT(*) AS OCCURENCES
  /* This is where I need to add HIGHEST_ID_GUY */
FROM Members
GROUP BY SUBSTR(id, LENGTH(id - 1), LENGTH(id))
ORDER BY LAST_NUMBER
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `id` is a number, then use arithmetic operations:

```
select mod(id, 10) as last_digit,
       count(*),
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by id desc) as name_at_biggest
from t
group by mod(id, 10);
```

If `id` is a string, then you need to convert to a number or something similar to define the "highest id".  For instance:

```
select substr(id, -1) as last_digit,
       count(*),
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by to_number(id) desc) as name_at_biggest
from t
group by substr(id, -1);
```